# io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking

Tags: android, socket.io

I Am developing an Android application using Socket.Io.When i use my local ip address (192.168.1.22:4000) i got respose from server.But when i use with domain Name ("http://mydomainname.com:80) I got io.socket.SocketIOException: Error while handshaking Exception how can i handle this.Please check below code>thanks in advance.

```
                  JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
                  js.put("key",value);
                    js.put("key",value);

                socket = new SocketIO();
         socket = new SocketIO("http://mydomain.com:80"); 


            socket.addHeader("id", 20);


        socket.connect(new IOCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  System.out.println(".....onMessage.......");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  System.out.println(".....onMessage... STR....");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect()
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("....connected ....");
             }

            @Override
    public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Object[] arguments = args;
                JSONObject jsb = (JSONObject) arguments[0];


                    } catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

        },js,"event name");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: is there no solution for this issue?